# I can have a generic fixture and call different values from that in my test?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I'm new on python and pytest, and at the momment I understand the basic of how work. But I can't find documentation to the below scenario:

I created a generic fixture that have the default mock values used in my project, and use this fixture in tests, it works fine. Something like:

```
#fixture
@pytest.fixture()
def generic_fixture(mocker):
    mocker.patch('project.some_class.url', "http://some_url:5002")

#test
def test_1(generic_fixture):
    do_something() # method that uses values from my generic fixture
    assert True
```

Now I want to know if have a way to pass a parameter in my test to my fixture call, to make some decision, something like:

```
#fixture
@pytest.fixture()
def generic_fixture(mocker, parameter_url):
    if parameter_url == None
        mocker.patch('project.some_class.url', "http://some_url:5002")
    else:
        mocker.patch('project.some_class.url', parameter_url)

#test
def test_1(generic_fixture(parameter_url)):
    do_something() # method that uses values from my generic fixture
    assert True
```

How I can do It properly? I looked at monkeypath, @pytest.mark.parametrize and some other structures, but none of them look to do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pytest's marks](https://pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#using-markers-to-pass-data-to-fixtures) for this.

```
#fixture
@pytest.fixture()
def generic_fixture(request, mocker):
    parameter_url = request.node.get_closest_marker("generic_fixture_url")
    ...

#test
@pytest.mark.generic_fixture_url("url")
def test_1(generic_fixture):
    ...
```

Other options are to turn your fixture into a [factory](https://pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#using-markers-to-pass-data-to-fixtures) or to [set some attribute](https://pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixtures-can-introspect-the-requesting-test-context) on the module of your test.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of D Malan help me a lot!

I'll put here my final solution, because I used what the above answer describe and other things, and I think it can be usefull for someone with similar structure, because at least for my was hard to figure it out (If is preferable, someone note me so I put this answer in the question):

conftest.py

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    # to avoid warnings
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "my_fixture_url")

@pytest.fixture()
    def my_fixture(request):
        if request.node.get_closest_marker("my_fixture_url") and request.node.get_closest_marker("my_fixture_url").args[0]:
            something = request.node.get_closest_marker("my_fixture_url").args[0]
        else:
            something = 'www.google.com'
            ...
```

test.py

```
@pytest.mark.my_fixture_url({'url': 'www.stackoverflow.com'})
def test_1(my_fixture):
    ...

def test_2(my_fixture):
    ...
```

I used a dictionary in my mark because I have situations where I want send more than one parameter, and/or use each one to override some default value.

Note I have a second test using the fixture but without marker. I can do it and use the default values from fixture.

This way I can use the same fixture in cases where I want the default values and in cases where I need to override part of the fixture configuration.

I hope it help someone :D

Comment: It is ok to post your solution as an answer. You could also accept the answer given by @DMalan, if it gave you the solution.

Comment: Thanks MrBean for remember me to mark some as correct answer. I let some time to see if someone have a different opinion. In this case, I'll mark mine, because like I say, @DMalan was really helpful to understand the part of structure I was in doubt. But I think the complete solution could be useful for someone, at least I didn't find any example of all parts, was really a challenge to me. If you disagree, let me know, so I can change it.